# GridView Remove Item C# 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0

What I need to do is to have the ability to remove an item from a Grid View and then update the recordset that it was removed.

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" Font-Size="X-Small">
                  <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="File" HeaderText="File" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Remove" HeaderText="Remove" />
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

// Backend...

```
    private void BindGridview(ArrayList list)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("File");
        dt.Columns.Add("Remove");
        int c = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[i]["file"] = list[i].ToString();
            dt.Rows[i]["Remove"] = ""; // <--- Have a remove action here????
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You could certainly use the AutoGenerateDeleteButton property of a GridView for this. Is there a reason you don't want to?

Comment: I didnt know about it. Lol.

Comment: What should I do on this? - - - - Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

Comment: Once you set the property, you have to write code in the code-behind to actually do the delete. Set the GridView's OnRowDeleting property to, for example, DeleteRow. Then write a DeleteRow method. You can see an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx